# Nobody's [defaults] but mine

Tags: discussion, status-completed, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to the [defaults](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defaults) tag.

This looks to be the very definition of a meta-tag. Every app will set these up differently, and whether or not they're changeable is up to each app. No one knows about app defaults *in general*. There is absolutely no context without other tags.

I think this tag should be burninated.

Currently on 9 questions:

- 1 about default font in draw.io
- 1 about default font color when pasting in Google Slides
- 1 about default Google Slides animation
- 1 about default sheet in Google Sheets
- 1 about setting the default view on YouTube
- 1 about setting the default of the Gmail pop-out window
- 1 about Google Analytics dashboard across multiple accounts
- 1 about sending messages in Facebook
- 1 about default phone type in Google Contacts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now complete - all [defaults](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defaults) have been removed.